# Wifi disabled but apps think I am using wifi

Tags: wi-fi

I am experience a really weird issue in my Android.
I disable wifi, i.e. completely disabled in settings menu, no wifi direct, no hotspot, nothing related to wifi. Also bluetooth disabled.

I use my LTE internet connection, it works normally.

However, I have at least two different and unrelated apps that claim I am using Wifi. And the issue is these two apps require for some reason some steps without wifi, i.e. with mobile data network.

Question: How can I fix this issue?

One could obviously think the apps are malfunctioning, but since two independent and unrelated apps are claiming both I am on a Wifi connection, might it be something not going smoothly in Android?

I tried to reinstall the apps, delete cache, add permissions, etc. No luck.

Phone is LG Velvet

[image]

Comment: Odd... I would ask what device, android version, etc... But it sounds like this is something with the apps themselves and a library or toolkit they use in common that has a bug. The other possibility here is your mobile data provider is giving an odd IP address that makes the app think it's on a WiFi connection.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about your phone model and manufacturer. As it happens with two apps this may be a bug of the installed system of your device model.